# Closed form of a sum involving powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How can one prove this equality ?

$$\sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{(mp)^k}{m!m^{k-m}}\quad =\quad \left(\frac{(mp)^m}{m!}\right)\left(\frac 1{1-p}\right), \quad p\lt 1$$

Comment: what do you mean with sum to $\alpha$?

Comment: sum to infinity.

Comment: Do you have any conditions on p? (like |p|<1)

Comment: yes it is less than 1.

Comment: then try to take the m out of the sum. And think about geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}\frac{(mp)^{k}}{m!\, m^{k-m}}=\frac{m^{m}}{m!}\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}\frac{(mp)^k}{m^k}=\frac{m^m}{m!}\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}p^{k}=\frac{m^m}{m!}\cdot\frac{p^m}{1-p}$$
(if $\lvert p\rvert <1$).

Comment: Hi, Thank you Bernard.

Comment: You're welcome.